# Change dependent objects based on a class attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

For example, if I have two classes :

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
     self.a = 1;

  def update(self, val):
     self.a = val;
class B:
  def __init__(self, default = A()):
     self.b = default.a;
```

Using them : 
`object_a = A(); object_b = B(object_a);`

Then, I would like to update the `object_a.a` attribute using `object_a.update(update_val)` but also **concurrently** update at all other dependent objects (`object_b.b` will also be updated to `update_val`).

How to do this in Python, is there a 'built-in' way?

I already have some manual solutions in mind, such as:

```
class A:
  def __init__(self):
     self.a = 1;
     self.dependent = None; 

  def update(self, val):
     self.a = val;
     if self.dependent != None:
        self.dependent.b = self.a;

class B:
  def __init__(self, default = A()):
     default.dependent = self;
     self.b = default.a;
```

Comment: You don't. The values are independent, just more references to an integer. Store a reference to the `A` instance instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I have an object of statistical data, and I would like to edit a value in a point, it would be convenient that all other statistical parameters/measurements (means, variance, etc) be updated automatically.

Comment: Sure, so then either re-calculate them all (using an event system, basically what you already thought of but more scalable), or only calculate those values when needed (so using a reference to then instance of `A`).

Comment: Please note that `default = A()` will create only one instance and use that one again and again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, what do you mean by "Store a reference to the `A`" ? I appreciate if you want to post answer, the site says my questions does not get good feedbacks, thanks.

Comment: @Arief: `self.source = instance_of_a`, then later on use `self.source.a` to reference the value there.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank, noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish what you are asking is use a mutable object, such as a list, to store the attribute's data.  Since the objects will reference the list, changing the values of the list will be shared to both objects.

Here is a version that uses a list to store the underlying value, but maintains the attribute behavior `.a` and `.b`

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = [1]

    def update(self, val):
        self._a[0] = val

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a[0]

class B:
    def __init__(self, default):
        self._b = default._a

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b[0]

a = A()
b = B(a)
a.update(4)

b.b
# returns:
4
```

Comment: Thanks. This is straightforward. I guess the 'builtin way' in Python is this way implicitly..